# Is printing an enum without a cast okay in C++?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <stdio.h> 

enum class TEST_ENUM{
    VALUE =1,
};

int main( ){
    // Gcc will warn. 
    printf("%u", TEST_ENUM::VALUE);

    // Both clang and gcc are happy. 
    printf("%u", uint32_T(TEST_ENUM::VALUE));
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/ehyn9Y)

In the above example, gcc will emit the following diagnostic:

```
<source>:8:12: warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'TEST_ENUM' [-Wformat=]

     printf("%u", TEST_ENUM::VALUE);
```

Regardless of compiler version or warnings enabled, I cannot seem to get clang to emit that same diagnostic. Since this is a warnning and not an error, I assume both are standards compliant. Why does gcc complain when clang won't? Is gcc being overly cautious here, or is there actually something worth warning about?

Comment: use `cout` instead of `printf`.  You'll get a compiler error from all compliant compilers.  Then you just write your own `operator <<` and `operator >>` for your enum type to get rid of the error.

Comment: I was providing a trivial example, the actual context where I'm encountering this issue is with using a logging library whose API takes format specifiers. Please don't tell me to use a more modern library, I'd love to :)

Comment: It isn't up to the compiler to tell you that your parameters to `printf` don't match what's in the format string. That's a relatively new capability that some (but not all) compilers support. While in this case it is harmless (because `enum TEST_ENUM`, which has `int` as the underlying type, and `unsigned` have the same size) there have been entire freight loads of bugs in code over the decades because the format string and parameters don't match.

Comment: There's a trick (I came across it somewhere here on SO) to define a `friend operator +` (*unary* plus operator)  for your `enum class` that returns an (unsigned) int, then just precede the argument with `+` each time you want the cast.

Comment: Just because some code compiles without error doesn't mean it's standards-compliant. Compilers are not required to diagnose undefined behavior at all.

Answer (score 3):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

> ... -     arguments specifying data to print. **If any argument after default conversions is not the type expected by the corresponding conversion specifier**, or if there are fewer arguments than required by format, the behavior is undefined. If there are more arguments than required by format, the extraneous arguments are evaluated and ignored

> Is gcc being overly cautious here, or is there actually something worth warning about?

Not at all overly cautios. You are passing a parameter of wrong type!

> Since this is a warnning and not an error, I assume both are standards compliant. Why does gcc complain when clang won't?

When your code has undefined behavior then compilers are not required to issue any diagnostics. GCC is just being nice to you here.

If you are forced to use a type-unsafe API you can always wrap it into something type-safe :

```
void Log(const TEST_ENUM& x) {
    the_actual_logging_api( "%u", static_cast<std:underlying_type<TEST_ENUM>>(x));   
}
```

Comment: I just tried with clang-10 on godbolt with `-Weverything` and it did not emit a warning for me.

Comment: You do realize none of those warnings are related to this discussion, right? They're all C++98 compatibility warnings.

Comment: @JoshuaRyan Sorry, I dont get you (neither the tone nor the message). Why does it matter where the warning comes from? You do get a warning. However, my answer also says that this warning is nothing you can count on

Comment: I don't mean to be hostile, but can you paste the exact text of the warning saying there is a type mismatch? It's possible I'm entirely missing what you're saying.

Comment: ok, the answer to your question is: no. I didnt realize that the warnings merely complain about using a scoped enum and have nothing to do with the format specifier. Clang also doesnt warn when you turn on `-Wformat` which makes me suspect that Clang does treat scoped enums with `printf` as an extension. I dont know Clang so I would have to search the manual. But that all doesnt help, because even if you can make clang emit a warning for one example I wouldn't count on getting a warning in all cases, because compilers do not have to warn for UB

Comment: @JoshuaRyan removed the PS and added a different note

Comment: For context, the reason I asked this question in the first place is because I'm working on a large codebase that's shared by multiple developers and I'm trying to allow developers the flexibility of using whatever compiler they want locally. My goal here was to get clang to catch this issue that gcc can catch since gcc is what I'm using for release and what I'm using in the build environment. I'm aware of type-safe non-va_args implementations, but there's tens of thousands of log call-sites and it isn't practical to cutover everywhere.

Comment: @JoshuaRyan I'd argue that using that logging API is a problem that needs to be fixed if not now then rather sooner than later. The log call-sites are not getting less over time, rather more ;). Anyhow I cant say anything useful without knowing the details.